# multiple topics subscribers with single callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

How to  create subscribers to multiple topics with single callback in cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215441/multiple-topics-subscribers-with-single-callback/) by [rosdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/22812/rosdino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look into [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package. This package filters messages from more than one subscribed topics and passes it to a single call back. All the subscribed topics need to have a time_stamp, for this to work.

---

Originally posted by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) with karma: 206 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/22812/rosdino/) on 2015-08-11**:
Hi, just have a doubt, does it work with rosserial arduino subscribers?

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2015-09-08**:
I may not be of help here. I do not use ROS on arduino.